# MKR FOx 1200 doesn't upload Sketch

Tags: sketch, uploading, port-mapping

My Arduino MKR Fox 1200 doesn't upload any sketches. First it worked, but now it doesn't.
It compiles the bare minimum sketch (empty loop and empty setup) but then uploads forever and after a long while it says port busy or Board not Found on Port

Answer (score 0):

I think that your Operating System has not found the board.  This could be for any number of reasons, not least a Windows update, if you have Windows :).

1. Close the IDE and unplug the board.
2. Wait 10 seconds.
3. Plug the board in, did the OS detect the board?
4. If NO, Unplug board and restart computer.
5. IF NO, When booted plug in board, did it detect the board -> No Stop.
6. If yes, start the IDE.
7. Check you have the write COM port selected.
8. Try loading a sketch again, did it work?

Other things to try:

- New USB cable
- Different USB port.
- Remove other USB devices, my Xbox controller sometimes prevents Arduinos attaching, not idea why.
- Different board.
- Different computer.